# an error while running a code that has 'lsim' command

Tags: matlab, runtime-error

I want to run the following code but I keep getting this error:

Error using DynamicSystem/lsim (line 85)
When simulating the response to a specific input signal, the input data U must be a
matrix with as many rows as samples in the time vector T, and as many columns as input
channels.

the code is:

---

```
V=300;
Vdc=700;
L=10*10^-3;
C=1500*10^-6;
R=1;
Dd=sqrt(2)*300/700;
w=2*pi*50;
A=[-R/L w -Dd/L 0 0;
    -w -R/L -Dd/L 0 0;
    (3*Dd)/2*C 0 0 0 0;
    0 1 0 0 0;
    0 0 1 0 0;];
B=[-Vdc/L 0;
    0 -Vdc/L;
    0 0;
    0 0;
    0 0;];
C=[1 0 0 0 0;
    0 1 0 0 0;
    0 0 1 0 0;];
D=[0 0;
    0 0;
    0 0;];
states={'id','iq','vdc','iq_dot','vdc_dot'};
inputs={'dd','dq'};
outputs={'id','iq','vdc'};
sys_ss=ss(A,B,C,D,'statename',states,'inputname',inputs,'outputname',outputs);
Q=eye(5);
I=eye(2);
K=lqr(A,B,Q,I);
Ac=[(A-B*K)];
Bc=[B];
Cc=[C];
Dc=[D];
states={'id','iq','vdc','iq_dot','vdc_dot'};
inputs={'r'};
outputs={'id','iq','vdc'};
sys_cl=ss(Ac,Bc,Cc,Dc,'statename',states,'inputname',inputs,'outputname',outputs);
x0=[0.1,0.1,0.1];
t=0:0.01:5;
r=zeros(size(t));
[y,t]=lsim(sys_cl,r,t,x0);
plot(t,y)
```

any help is highly appreciated.

---

Comment: I think the problem is that the input data for `lsim` must be a matrix `r` with as many rows as samples in the vector `t`, and as many columns as inputs in `sys_cls`. But your inputs are not the right size.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply. I am well aware of the error. the problem I don't know how to correct as I am not well versed in Matlab programming. any correction tips would be very appreciated

Comment: Make `r` have the same number of rows as samples in `t`, and the same number of columns as inputs in `sys_cl`. As it is you are doing `r=zeros(size(t))` which will make `r` the same size as `t`. Use `r=zeros(R,C)` where `R` is the number of samples in `t`, and `C` is the number of inputs in `sys_cl`.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks very much I modified the line to  r=zeros(501,2) and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

You make two mistakes, use command 'help lsim' to look up instructions.

```
[yout,x] = lsim(a, b, c, d, u, t, x0)
```

1.The matrix U has as many columns as inputs in SYS and its i-th row specifies the input value at time T(i).
2.The length of the initial condition X0 must match the number of states.

So, I change your code like this:

```
sys_cl=ss(Ac,Bc,Cc,Dc,'statename',states,'inputname',inputs,'outputname',outputs);
x0=[0.1,0.1,0.1, 0.1,0.1];
t=0:0.01:5;
r=zeros(length(inputs), length(t));
[y,t]=lsim(sys_cl,r,t,x0);
```